# jQuery resizable handles visible when clicked and hide when clicked elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery's resizable handles and I use `autohide: true` to hide the handles.

My question is how can I make the handles visible when the relevant div is clicked and turn the handles off when clicked somewhere out of the relevant div.

```
    jQuery('#dragDiv').resizable({
          containment: $('#wrapper'),
          handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw',
          //autoHide: true
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a click handler to the document to add/remove a focus class which you can use to control the style/visibility of the handles?

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $('.resizable').removeClass('focus');
  $resizable = $(e.target).closest('.resizable');
  if ($resizable.length) {
    $resizable.addClass('focus');
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/rocepamiwu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: `$('.resizable')` are dynamically created. So instead of `$(document).on('click', function(e) {` I used `$('body').on('click', '.resizable', function() {` but still doesn't work?

Comment: I've updated the answer to support multiple dynamically created resizable elements.